# Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium, saucelabs, cucumber-serenity

Getting the below error while try running in sauce lab. I am not sure what is the issue to apply fix here. Could someone extend help?

[image]

**Note:** Secure remote tunnel is provisioned and running successfully.

**Command:**

```
mvn clean verify -Dwebdriver.driver="remote" -Dsaucelabs.browserName="chrome" -Dsaucelabs.browserVersion="102" -Dsaucelabs.platformName="windows 10" -Dsaucelabs.url="https://foo:boo@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub" -Denv="dev" -Dwebdriver.base.url="https://test.com/login" -Dsaucelabs.accessKey="foo" -Dsaucelabs.username="boo" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@test" -Dsaucelabs.tunnelName="koo" -Dsaucelabs.tunnelOwner="boo" -Dsaucelabs.name="POC" -Dwebdriver.remote.url="https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
package xyz.abc;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"},
        features = "Test",
        glue = "fooboo"
)
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**Expected Results:-**
Execution should take place in sauce labs.

**Actual Results:-**
Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not setting your Sauce Labs user and API key, which ends up as an unauthorized request.